# SSRS - After action go to same report, I can´t change search

Tags: reporting-services, filter, refresh

In ssrs, I use the Go To Report action calling the same report passing the same parameters and some more to a stored procedure in the same report. But after loading the same report again I can not do a new search, the report loads with the parameters of the first search, before the action. I even change the parameters, but when I click on View Report to search again the parameters return to the first search and the search result does not change.

Example:

1 - I set the parameter 'Termo de Acordo Vigente' to : [POSSUI] and I clicked on View Report, and the report filters correctly :

[image]

2 - I click on the action to go to the same report, inside the field 'FL PLANEJAMENTO' :

[image]

3 - I changed the parameter 'Termo de Acordo Vigente' to : [NAO POSSUI] and I clicked on View Report to change search result

4 - But after click on View Report, the report simply not load and reset the parameter 'Termo de Acordo Vigente' to [POSSUI].

What am I doing wrong?
I realize this happens after the action go to same report, where I set the parameters the report again in the action.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots to your question?  It is hard to work out what you are experiencing from your description alone.

Comment: iamdavi - Sorry, but I could only add 2 pictures because of my reputation

Comment: Do you have a default value set on the parameter?

Comment: Alan Schofield  - Yes, but I removed all the default values of parameters and the report continues without reloading after the action goes to the same report.

Comment: Wait, so how is your report opening up the first time? If your report takes a parameter, it needs a parameter to be able to show anything. Have you set `Default Values` to the report? Or does the report parameter take `null`/`blank` values?

Comment: Crazy Cucumber - The parameters have default values